# Check if a view model property is a string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following foreach in a view, I would like it to iterate over properties in my view model and display a text box for every property that is a string.

```
foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
        {
            if(property.GetType() == "string")
            {
                <div class="watermark">
                    <label>Friend's email address</label>
                    <br>
                    @Html.Editor(property.PropertyName)
                </div>
            }
        }
```

Ideally property.GetType() == "string"  would return a true or false, but this is not the case because .GetType is always returning System.Type (I believe).

Comment: why are you looping through the properties? why not use `Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty)`.

Comment: I have 10 email properties in this view model, it seemed silly to copy paste that 10 times so I was going to loop through the strings for the editors.

Comment: Found it, needed to be

if(property.ModelType.Name == "String")

Comment: i answered your other question stating how you can avoid the loop/copy + paste 10 times. obviously you did not see it and/or choose not to follow it. this solution is wrong on so many levels.

Comment: Yes, this is not using the M in MVC (in the conventional way)

Comment: @TGH I think I see why that is now, thanks.

Comment: @RPM1984 You are correct, I did not see it as it was posted several hours after many other correct solutions were posted and I had moved on.

Thanks for answering, and making your way over to this question to tell me how wrong I was.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(property.GetType() == typeof(string))
```